# Create database and user in mongoDB official docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I want to have a MongoDB service running in a Docker in order to serve a Flask app. What I've tried is create a container using `docker-compose.yml`:

```
my_mongo_service:
  image: mongo
  environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${MY_DATABASE_NAME}
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  volumes:
    - "/data/db:/data/db"
  command: mongod
```

Imagine we have an `.env` file like this:

```
MONGO_ROOT_USER=my_fancy_username
MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_fancy_password
MY_DATABASE_NAME=my_fancy_database
```

What I would expect (reading [the doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)) is that a database matching `MY_DATABASE_NAME` value is created and an user matching `MONGO_ROOT_USER` is created too and I could authenticate with the pair (`MONGO_ROOT_USER`,`MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD`).

Ok, I launch my container with `docker-compose up` and enter on it with `docker exec -it <container-id> bash`. I put `mongo` on the console and when I try to authenticate it crashes:

```
> use my_fancy_database
switched to db my_fancy_database
> db.auth('my_fancy_username','my_fancy_password')
Error: Authentication failed.
0
```

On the log, the error I find is the following

```
[...] authentication failed for my_fancy_username on my_fancy_database from client [...] ; UserNotFound: Could not find user my_fancy_username@my_fancy_database
```

The `docker-compose.yml` configuration (as it was posted on official documentation) is not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. Are you using environmental variables, which are not in the environment? It sure looks so.

If you do `echo $MY_DATABASE_NAME` in your terminal and see empty output, then here is the answer to your question. You either first have to define the variable with `export` (or `source` for a file) or redefine your `docker-compose.yml`.

For that, it's best to use `env_file` directive:

```
my_mongo_service:
  image: mongo
  env_file:
      - .env
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  volumes:
    - "/data/db:/data/db"
```

And set your `.env` as this:

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=my_fancy_username
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_fancy_password
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=my_fancy_database
```

Side note: using `command: mongod` is not necessary, the base image is already using it.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your comments. I will use `env_file` directive, but anyway, in the docker container bash I've used `env` command and it appear the correct values for those variables.